# Using parfor in MATLAB for indirect indexing of an array

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am currently trying to parallelize my script for runtime benefits.

My code includes a segment, which has the following form when represented in a very abstract way:

```
x=zeros(5,1);

y{1}=[1; 3; 5];
y{2}=[2; 4];

parfor i=1:2
    x(y{i})= func(y{i});
end
```

So, I want to populate the indices of the variable `x` not sequentially, but in a parallel way. This gives me, however, the following error:

```
The variable x in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

The indices to be assigned are always disjoint (such as the example `[1; 3; 5]` and `[2; 4]`) i.e. no overwriting of entries will occur during the parallel run, which would have otherwise jeopardized the non-sequential processing.

Is there perhaps another way to reformulate this functionality?

Comment: MATLAB cannot know ahead of time that the splitting you apply is disjoint. You need to make this explicit. For example by collecting the outputs in a cell array and re-combining them into `x` when you're done processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use structs since output size is changing.

```
x=zeros(5,1);
y{1}=[1; 3; 5];
y{2}=[2; 4];

parfor i=1:2
    temp{i}= sin(y{i});
end

for i=1:2
    x(y{i})=temp{i};
end
```

Comment: You should preallocate `temp`, to prevent resizing. You could also use `temp{i}=...`, instead of a struct array, which looks simpler to me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I edited it with cell array. It also does not require preallocation. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocate-memory-for-a-cell-array.html

Comment: In this code, `temp{i}` will enlarge the cell array each loop iteration, meaning that it will need to be reallocated. The contents of the cell array will not be copied, but the cell array itself will. You won't notice this in such a short loop, but in general this will slow down your code significantly. Simply do `temp=cell(2,1)` before the loop to pre-allocate the cell array.

Comment: I tested, you are right. I thought that page meant no preallocation was necessary.